# Returning an Int and a Complex Type from a stored procedure using Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5, multiple-resultsets

I have a project where I have been given a stored procedure that I must use. It is used to create a new record in the database. It returns an `Int32` which is the new ID of the record in the table. It also has a temp table where errors are stored and sent back in a second result. So basically the last two lines are

```
SELECT @NewID
SELECT * From @ErrorsTable
```

I have to use Entity Framework to call the stored procedure. My problem I can't figure out how to get both return results.

The default When updating from the Database is to just return an `Int32`. I tried following some examples where they do multiple return results from a stored procedure but I think its not working for me because all the examples return multiple complex types, and I have a mix of a scalar and complex type.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I ended up solving it by mostly following the code code only option at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

I added a new method to my Repository that returned called a stored procedure and returned multiple results sets. Something along these lines

```
Public Object[] StoredProcCall(string storedProc, SqlDbParams sqlParams, type[] types)
{
    var cmd = dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = storedProc;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if(parameters != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
        object[] mObj = new object[types.Count];
        for(int i = 0; i < types.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(AutoMapper.Mapper).GetMethod("DynamicMap", new Type[] { typeof(object)});
            var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(types[i]);
            objected mappedData = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { reader});
            mObj[i] = mappedData;
            if(!reader.NextResult())
                break;

        }
        return mObj;
    }
    finally
    {
        dbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
    }

}
```

The only think is that for that to work I had to make a class that that consist of only one property which is my simple type. and every type in the array needs to be IEnumerable which is ok in my case. But That is the basics of what I did and can be changed as needed.